# Error message is causing Error Log to grow out of control

Tags: sql-server

The error log is growing like crazy - in one day it has reached 32GB.

There is one error that keeps being logged.

I have searched online for this error, however I couldn't find any helpful solutions.

> Error: 8354, Severity: 16, State: 1.
>
> Event Tracing for Windows failed to send an event. Send failures with the same error code may not be reported in the future. Error ID: 997, Event class ID: 12, Cause: 997(Overlapped I/O operation is in progress.).

I want to add that this happened after updating the security patches by the System admin.

Sql Server 2012 running on windows 2008/R2

Comment: Sounds like a call to Microsoft Support may be in order.

Comment: sebeid - Is my answer below worth salvaging for your inquiry any or shall I delete the post? If it didn't help you, then I'm fine to remove it. If it did help then I'll be happy to quote reference and make my answer better and more appropriate.

Comment: Did this ever get resolved? I've deleted my answer as it had three links and no detail and I'm not going to spend time quoting that content since apparently it didn't help you any. If I hear back otherwise from you then I 'll be glad to undelete and clean it up, etc.